# Erro 255 ao rodar o NPX

Tags: react

Eu não consigo criar um app React. Já tentei o npm cache clear --force e tb tentei instalar no global, mas nada funciona. Log do erro:

pm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /home/prihscapin/.npm/_cacache/content-v2/sha512/14/21/2143fe2b135cd8bfdad85c9c3f9ac46ab279a58dee631cfea1b9678167bd388d44f2d36739019c96ba3a4c4756b1ea6570f4dc8931fb8ad8230359521f80
npm ERR! errno -1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Your cache folder contains root-owned files, due to a bug in
npm ERR! previous versions of npm which has since been addressed.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! To permanently fix this problem, please run:
npm ERR!   sudo chown -R 1001:1001 "/home/prihscapin/.npm"

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/prihscapin/.npm/_logs/2021-07-06T15_49_03_565Z-debug.log
Instalação de [ 'create-react-app@latest' ] falhou com código 255

Obrigadão desde já! :)

Answer (score 0):

Roda sudo npm ERR! sudo chown -R 1001:1001 "/home/prihscapin/.npm" se não funcionar tenta também: sudo npx create-react-app my-app.

Ou sudo su e depois npx.